# How can I access properties of an object in an array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, object

I have an array of objects `_schedule.games` I want to display the Game property opponent in each game as I loop through the schedule.

```
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [_schedule.games count]; i++)
    {
        Game *game = [_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i];
        game.opponent = ((Game *) [_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i]).opponent;
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, 100)];

        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", game.opponent] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [_gameScrollList addSubview:button];

        x += button.frame.size.width;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding all buttons at same position. You are not using x in setting frame. So all buttons are added at same location.

Comment: Print game.opponent in console and what is the use of rewriting this line. `game.opponent = ((Game *) [_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i]).opponent;` if you can directly access game .opponent

Comment: @NishantTyagi I forgot to change "x" back,  it prints (null) but gives me two buttons *The array has 2 objects

Comment: Ya button title will not display anything if it is null. and loop iterates two times thats why two buttons are there. So first print your schedule.games array and check are you getting opponents there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
    Game *game = [_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i];
```

gives you the game instance inside the array,So no need to assign the property again as

```
game.opponent = ((Game *) [_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i]).opponent;
```

`game.opponent` has the value that is in the array object property and so you can call it directly as `game.opponent` .

2.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", game.opponent]` says `game.opponent` is a string so no need to typecast it again as a `NSString`

So the method will be as

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [_schedule.games count]; i++)
{
    Game *game = (Game *)[_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, 100)];
    [button setTitle:game.opponent forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_gameScrollList addSubview:button];
    x += button.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of incrementing x in the loop ? Its not used anywhere in the above code. The CGRect(20,0,100,100) in your code should be replaced with CGRect(x+20,0,100,100); to bring it in effect.

Comment: I answered the question alone.Your point is right by the way,that increment should be used with x or y in setting the proper frame else buttons overlap

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 I use x, just made a change and forgot to change it back when I posted.  It turns out that I wasn't init my game correctly, thus game.opponent was null. However, I'm going to accept your answer as it's a little cleaner than my method without the extra code that I didn't need. Thanks